# Why script-migration generate all migration script instead of the last migration?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Let's say I have add two migrations using EF Core. Let's say this is the filename in Migration folder

- 20210619063616_base.cs
- 20210619064501_removePersonModel.cs

When I `20210619063616_base.cs` is generated, I run `script-migration`, it generated the sql version of the migration.

Then, when run another `add-migration` and when I run `script-migration`, it generated *all* the sql including the previous migration.

How can I run `script-migration` just to generate sql which includes only last migration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why script-migration generate all migration script instead of the last migration?

[Script-Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#script-migration) command has two optional parameters called `From` and `To`, which allow you to specify respectively the starting and ending migration:

> - `-From <String>` The starting migration. Migrations may be identified by name or by ID. The number 0 is a special case that means before the first migration. Defaults to 0.
> - `-To <String>`   The ending migration. Defaults to the last migration.

As you can see, the default for ending migration is the last, but for starting it is the special number 0 meaning starting from the first inclusive.

> How can I run `script-migration` just to generate sql which includes only last migration ?

One may consider the `From` default to be a poor design choice, but it is what it is, so what you need is to explicitly provide that parameter. For instance, to generate the script for `removePersonModel` migration,  you would use

```
Script-Migration -From base
```

if it is the last migration, or generally (regardless of which is the current last migration)

```
Script-Migration -From base -To removePersonModel
```

Comment: Nice! Such a simple argument and I had some trouble to find it. Thanks! 